# Display image which is stored in database in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to display image of the logged in user using session in Laravel but I am an getting error. And I think it may be due to quotations.

This is my code:

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('img/'".{{Session::get('admin-pic')}}."'')}}" class="img-circle"/>
```

Error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '".{{Session::get('admin-pic'))' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel/blog/resources/views/admin-profile.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `{{}}` inside another one, actually you can't:

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('img/'.Session::get('admin-pic'))}}" class="img-circle"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`{{}}` will be rendered to `echo` and you can't nest `echo`. Also, you can just use the `asset()` and `session` helpers. So, the correct syntax:

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/' . session('admin-pic')) }}" class="img-circle"/>
```